# Rapid insmod and rmmod leads to vmalloc allocation failure. Is this a memory leak?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, kernel, drivers

I have a more conceptual question than "please debug my kernel oops".

I wrote a fairly long device driver and compiled it as a LKM. I wanted to see if there were any memory leaks, so I wrote a shell script to insmod, wait, then rmmod it. After about 4000 attempts, I received a message:

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module testmod.ko: Cannot allocate memory

The kernel is not panicked, and my memory usage from "top" shows that used/resident memory is really quite low.

I will put the dmesg log after this, but on a more general level, is this type of error associated with not freeing structures within the module itelf? Is there a kernel limit to the number of times you can insert a module, or number of modules inserted? I know I can add a bootarg to increase the vmalloc space, but I'd like to understand what's going on first.

```
[ 6393.474859] alloc_vmap_area: 105 callbacks suppressed
[ 6393.474875] vmap allocation for size 20480 failed: use vmalloc=<size> to increase size.
[ 6393.474888] warn_alloc_failed: 105 callbacks suppressed
[ 6393.474899] vmalloc: allocation failure: 14808 bytes
[ 6393.474909] insmod: page allocation failure: order:0, mode:0x24000c2
[ 6393.474925] CPU: 1 PID: 24012 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           O    4.4.0-snickerdoodle #26
[ 6393.474934] Hardware name: Xilinx Zynq Platform
[ 6393.474975] [<c0016080>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c00123f0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[ 6393.475003] [<c00123f0>] (show_stack) from [<c01d2b40>] (dump_stack+0x80/0xcc)
[ 6393.475028] [<c01d2b40>] (dump_stack) from [<c00945fc>] (warn_alloc_failed+0xe4/0x110)
[ 6393.475050] [<c00945fc>] (warn_alloc_failed) from [<c00b82ac>] (__vmalloc_node_range+0x1c4/0x1e8)
[ 6393.475069] [<c00b82ac>] (__vmalloc_node_range) from [<c00b830c>] (__vmalloc_node+0x3c/0x4c)
[ 6393.475085] [<c00b830c>] (__vmalloc_node) from [<c00b8340>] (vmalloc+0x24/0x34)
[ 6393.475104] [<c00b8340>] (vmalloc) from [<c0077620>] (copy_module_from_fd+0x54/0xf8)
[ 6393.475123] [<c0077620>] (copy_module_from_fd) from [<c007a2e0>] (SyS_finit_module+0x44/0x6c)
[ 6393.475142] [<c007a2e0>] (SyS_finit_module) from [<c000eb80>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x3c)
[ 6393.475150] Mem-Info:
[ 6393.475176] active_anon:2118 inactive_anon:45 isolated_anon:0
[ 6393.475176]  active_file:9388 inactive_file:1367 isolated_file:0
[ 6393.475176]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
[ 6393.475176]  slab_reclaimable:1873 slab_unreclaimable:2028
[ 6393.475176]  mapped:1826 shmem:49 pagetables:87 bounce:0
[ 6393.475176]  free:239472 free_pcp:342 free_cma:4028
[ 6393.475227] Normal free:702340kB min:16384kB low:20480kB high:24576kB active_anon:6176kB inactive_anon:160kB active_file:35636kB inactive_file:4460kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:786432kB managed:769096kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5256kB shmem:164kB slab_reclaimable:7492kB slab_unreclaimable:8112kB kernel_stack:704kB pagetables:244kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:760kB local_pcp:528kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[ 6393.475237] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2048 2048
[ 6393.475280] HighMem free:255548kB min:256kB low:1652kB high:3048kB active_anon:2296kB inactive_anon:20kB active_file:1916kB inactive_file:1008kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:262144kB managed:262144kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:2048kB shmem:32kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:104kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:608kB local_pcp:320kB free_cma:16112kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[ 6393.475289] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
[ 6393.475303] Normal: 157*4kB (UME) 57*8kB (UME) 20*16kB (UME) 13*32kB (UME) 1*64kB (M) 2*128kB (UM) 3*256kB (UME) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (U) 170*4096kB (UM) = 702300kB
[ 6393.475370] HighMem: 113*4kB (UM) 98*8kB (UM) 63*16kB (UMC) 28*32kB (UMC) 12*64kB (UMC) 4*128kB (MC) 1*256kB (U) 2*512kB (MC) 2*1024kB (UC) 3*2048kB (UMC) 59*4096kB (MC) = 255556kB
[ 6393.475437] 10803 total pagecache pages
[ 6393.475446] 0 pages in swap cache
[ 6393.475456] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[ 6393.475463] Free swap  = 0kB
[ 6393.475470] Total swap = 0kB
[ 6393.475477] 262144 pages RAM
[ 6393.475484] 65536 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[ 6393.475491] 4334 pages reserved
[ 6393.475497] 4096 pages cma reserved
root@linaro-developer:/home/linaro/drop#
```

Comment: IIRC, there is no limit on the number of times a module can be inserted/removed. Might be a memory leak indeed. If vmalloc cannot allocate 15-20 Kb, it definitely looks like the space available for allocation has  been exhausted. It seems, you are running it on ARM, so, I guess, using kmemleak tool might be an option if the leak is not obvious.